Microsoft Word (Office Home 2016) displays FORMTEXT rather than value
For all text fields and checkboxes, my version of Microsoft Word Home 2016 does not display entered values but the field type, as in the attached image.
A screenshot of the field problem:

I have already tried Alt+F9, as well as using a custom "Update Fields" button in the ribbon.
Edit: On checking, the "Show field codes instead of their values" in Options>Advanced is greyed out:
Word Options>Advanced screenshot

Does {ADDIN EN.CITE} error codes in your Word document – Alfasoft Support & Knowledgebase answer your question?

@DavidPostill The article you shared suggests unchecking "Show field codes instead of their values", but this option is greyed out.

Did you install any 3rd-party add-in which may affect this "Show field codes instead of their values" option? Please go to Options > Add-ins > Manage, COM add-ins > Go, uncheck any enabled add-ins to have a check. Or you may go to Control panel, perform an online repair for your Office.

For a FORMTEXT field to function correctly, you have in any case to enable the correct form of Document Protection, e.g. using the option in the Developer Tab, which you may have to enable in Word Options.

Resolved: File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Check 'Developer' in the right panel > Click on the Developer tab in the ribbon > COM Add-ins > Disabled 'EndNote Cite While you Write' and 'OneNote Linked Notes Add-in' and OK
Click on the Developer tab in the ribbon > Restrict editing > Stop protection > Uncheck 'Allow only this type of editing in the document'
File > Options > Advanced > Uncheck "Show field codes instead of their values"
